# What's the difference between Festive PEI and normal PEI maps?

Tags: unturned

In a recent update, a Festive PEI map was added to Unturned.

What's the differences between the Festive and non-Festive versions of the map?

Answer (score 2):

Christmas Trees are added to towns in the map, as well as christmas lights hanging from the ceilings of buildings in towns.

[image: trees]

Additionally, christmas lights barbed wire and barbed wire fences were added to the game.

[image: barbed wire]

Answer (score 0):

Festive PEI map have christmas trees scattered around the island which spawn items underneath it and you will be freezing much like Yukon map. That's a lot harder with temperature system.